# Slide curtain button action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Thank you in advance for your help.

I came about this curtain animation code, where I made some changes, and one of them is to have a button to slide the curtain up, and show the content behind.

I tried adding the method scrollTop, but did not work. :-(

```js
  function curtain() {
    var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
    var scrollPosition = $( document ).scrollTop();
    var value = - ( windowHeight );
    var mainHeight = $( "#main" ).height();
    var bodyHeight = windowHeight + mainHeight;
    if (windowHeight - scrollPosition <= 0) {
      $( "#curtain" ).css({position: "fixed", top: value});
      $( "#main" ).css({position: "static", marginTop: windowHeight});
      $('body').height(mainHeight);
    }
    else {
      $( "#curtain" ).css({position: "static", height: windowHeight});
      $( "#main" ).css({position: "fixed", top: value, marginTop: windowHeight});
      $('body').height(bodyHeight);
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(curtain);
  $(window).resize(curtain);
  $(window).scroll(curtain);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#curtain {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
#curtain p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#curtain a {
    background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .8em 1em;
  border-radius: 4px
}
#curtain img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100Vh;  
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="curtain">
    <p>
    <a href="#" class="curtain-action">Show me the content</a>
    </p>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
</div>
<div id="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae metus tellus. Curabitur elementum mauris nec ligula dictum hendrerit. Integer ut magna congue, fermentum risus sed, facilisis erat. Proin mattis eros ac urna tincidunt ornare. Nulla non sapien volutpat, consequat erat id, ornare enim. Fusce metus enim, sodales id semper vel, gravida ut ante. Nulla rhoncus tortor neque, sit amet tincidunt nibh ullamcorper quis. Nulla ac erat et ipsum semper euismod. Vestibulum at fermentum neque. Sed congue lorem eros, scelerisque cursus magna auctor ut. Ut vitae sagittis urna. Duis id convallis velit.</p>
    <p>Donec vestibulum est tempus, dictum mi sit amet, blandit orci. Cras mattis luctus augue. Integer varius venenatis neque. Nullam tempor dignissim massa, a vehicula dolor aliquam vestibulum. Maecenas ac neque a massa ultricies condimentum. Sed vehicula eleifend elit. Nunc blandit justo malesuada sagittis mollis. Vestibulum turpis massa, vestibulum ac libero nec, lobortis congue nisl.</p>
    <p>Sed elementum eleifend tellus, in dapibus ligula volutpat sed. Curabitur rhoncus eu sapien placerat commodo. Aliquam posuere turpis in mauris pulvinar pulvinar. Praesent sed nisi vitae augue imperdiet dictum. Morbi ornare eros id mauris ultrices, vestibulum posuere ante tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque erat turpis, faucibus at eros non, ornare fringilla lorem. Sed mollis cursus lectus sit amet consequat. Duis in sodales leo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae metus tellus. Curabitur elementum mauris nec ligula dictum hendrerit. Integer ut magna congue, fermentum risus sed, facilisis erat. Proin mattis eros ac urna tincidunt ornare. Nulla non sapien volutpat, consequat erat id, ornare enim. Fusce metus enim, sodales id semper vel, gravida ut ante. Nulla rhoncus tortor neque, sit amet tincidunt nibh ullamcorper quis. Nulla ac erat et ipsum semper euismod. Vestibulum at fermentum neque. Sed congue lorem eros, scelerisque cursus magna auctor ut. Ut vitae sagittis urna. Duis id convallis velit.</p>
    <p>Donec vestibulum est tempus, dictum mi sit amet, blandit orci. Cras mattis luctus augue. Integer varius venenatis neque. Nullam tempor dignissim massa, a vehicula dolor aliquam vestibulum. Maecenas ac neque a massa ultricies condimentum. Sed vehicula eleifend elit. Nunc blandit justo malesuada sagittis mollis. Vestibulum turpis massa, vestibulum ac libero nec, lobortis congue nisl.</p>
    <p>Sed elementum eleifend tellus, in dapibus ligula volutpat sed. Curabitur rhoncus eu sapien placerat commodo. Aliquam posuere turpis in mauris pulvinar pulvinar. Praesent sed nisi vitae augue imperdiet dictum. Morbi ornare eros id mauris ultrices, vestibulum posuere ante tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque erat turpis, faucibus at eros non, ornare fringilla lorem. Sed mollis cursus lectus sit amet consequat. Duis in sodales leo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae metus tellus. Curabitur elementum mauris nec ligula dictum hendrerit. Integer ut magna congue, fermentum risus sed, facilisis erat. Proin mattis eros ac urna tincidunt ornare. Nulla non sapien volutpat, consequat erat id, ornare enim. Fusce metus enim, sodales id semper vel, gravida ut ante. Nulla rhoncus tortor neque, sit amet tincidunt nibh ullamcorper quis. Nulla ac erat et ipsum semper euismod. Vestibulum at fermentum neque. Sed congue lorem eros, scelerisque cursus magna auctor ut. Ut vitae sagittis urna. Duis id convallis velit.</p>
    <p>Donec vestibulum est tempus, dictum mi sit amet, blandit orci. Cras mattis luctus augue. Integer varius venenatis neque. Nullam tempor dignissim massa, a vehicula dolor aliquam vestibulum. Maecenas ac neque a massa ultricies condimentum. Sed vehicula eleifend elit. Nunc blandit justo malesuada sagittis mollis. Vestibulum turpis massa, vestibulum ac libero nec, lobortis congue nisl.</p>
    <p>Sed elementum eleifend tellus, in dapibus ligula volutpat sed. Curabitur rhoncus eu sapien placerat commodo. Aliquam posuere turpis in mauris pulvinar pulvinar. Praesent sed nisi vitae augue imperdiet dictum. Morbi ornare eros id mauris ultrices, vestibulum posuere ante tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque erat turpis, faucibus at eros non, ornare fringilla lorem. Sed mollis cursus lectus sit amet consequat. Duis in sodales leo.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to change a couple of things as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/Lszxpear/).

1. Add a click handler to your button: `$('.curtain-action').click( curtain );`
2. Replace your `curtain` function code with:

   ```
   $('#curtain').animate( {top: '-'+$('#curtain').height() }, 1000 )
   ```
3. Change your `curtain` div css to:

   ```
   #curtain {
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need what you commented. That is the curtain. :-(

Comment: Can you check again if that is what you meant - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/Lszxpear/

Comment: This is where I got stuck. Once I click "show me the content", the curtain slides, and I can't see it no more.

Comment: The curtain shows/hide on scroll. If I press the button, it slides up. If I then scroll, the curtain should still scroll up/down.